# My Effect is called only once when I dispatch multiples

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I dispatch a lot of event when I load a set of drones. I would like for each drones loaded, to dispatch connect to a SSE service so I do the following

```
      drones.forEach((drone) => {
        console.log('dispatch', drone.id)
        this.store$.dispatch(new UsedDronesStoreActions.OpenUsedDroneUpdatePositionChannelRequest({ droneId: drone.id, projectId : environment.projectId }));
      });
```

My effect

```
  @Effect()
  startStatusUpdate$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.OpenUsedDroneUpdateStatusChannelRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.OpenUsedDroneUpdateStatusChannelRequest),
    concatMap((action) =>
      this.droneDataService.openUsedDroneUpdateStatusChannel(action.payload).pipe(
        map(result => { console.log('there', action.payload.droneId);}),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => { }),
      )
    )
  );
```

is called only once

```
dispatch id1
dispatch id2
dispatch id3

there id1
===> no more
```

I tried concatMap, and switchMap booth don7t do (concat only show the first value, switch the last)

switchMap do only the last cause he unsubscribe from the previous
concatMap will not subscribe to the other cause the first one isn't completed...

Is there one that subscribe to everyone and watch them one by one separately ?

Comment: I assume mergeMap can help.
About mergeMap - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you getting any errors in the console? An Effect should always return an `Action` (unless `dispatch: false` is being used).

The line

```
  map(result => { console.log('there', action.payload.droneId);}),
```

Does not return an action and causes the Effect to be destroyed.